# UIScrollView Updating contentSize Causes Scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I have a `UIScrollView` that has a single child view within it.  If I set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` immediately after creation, everything works as I expect and I get scrolling.

The challenge is the view within the `UIScrollView` is dynamically sized.  The width is fixed, but the height is unknown at the time I set up the scrollview.

When I do a `[scrollView setContentSize:CGRectMake(...)]` after the inner view does it's thing, the scrollview updates to the proper size and scrolling works.  So basic scrolling works fine.

However, the major problem is that when I `setContentSize` at a later point, the `UIScrollView` decides to scroll down(with animation) towards the end of the scrollview, which is not what I want, I want the scroll to stay at the top, and let the contents within the scrollview either get bigger or smaller, without changing the apparent scroll position.

What am I missing?

Comment: I certainly hope you're not passing a CGRect to `-setContentSize:`.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for catching that. Should be CGSizeMake(which is in fact what I have in the code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you also call `[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0)];` when you call the setContentSize?

Comment: Thanks for the response. You led me to think of why the offset wouldn't be 0,0 in the first place.  The problem was I was initializing the content offset to a height larger than the window itself, so when the content size changed the scrollview probably wanted to keep it's original position.  Not initializing the content size fixed the behavior and it does not move.

Answer (score 0):

To force `UIScrollView` to scroll only e.g. horizontally, I always set non-scrollable value for `contentSize` to 0, using:

```
CGSizeMake(contentSize.width, 0).
```